# Asp.net core - Open a different website and get cookies after user logged into that website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcookie

I have a console asp.net core application, which opens a website (that is already present). The website asks for user login and password. Now, when the user logs in, i need to get the cookies in my asp.net core app.

Also, another question. Can this asp.net core then create a HTTP request and send these cookies to another application acting as a web server?

Please note that i am a complete newbie to asp.net. So, kindly help!

The following is the code i have for opening the URL, which is working fine.

//Program.cs

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseKestrel()
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .Build();

        host.Start();
        OpenBrowser("https://mywebsite.com/auth/samlsso.php");
    }

    public static void OpenBrowser(string url)
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}"));
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
        }
        else
        {
            // throw 
        }
    }
}   




 //startup.cs

namespace SampleCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Run(appContext =>
            {
                return appContext.Response.WriteAsync("Hey, I'm from Web!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to implement single sign on. This is not how you would usually do that; your solution is a hack. Most solutions would redirect from your web application to a authentication provider with some parameter that tells the provider which page in your application to redirect to when the user has been authenticated. When the authentication provider redirects to your page it may set a cookie, include a parameter or post data  that you will use in later requests to authenticated resources.

Comment: It would seem you are a newbie to web development in general. Cookies are domain-bound. What you're attempting to do is explicitly forbidden, because it would allow any site to hijack any other site's user accounts. What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve; maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: Yes you both are right..the website i am talking about uses single sign on to authenticate a user. This site has been configured to use IDP for authentication. I have an application which needs to allow an user to use single sign on credentials. This is by using the website above (and the IDP configured there). I need a way to get the cookies from this website after authentication and pass it back to my application. The application will then use these cookies and connect to the server.

Comment: And also, this needs to be cross platform, since the same needs to work on Windows and Mac...and when i say application, it's a C++ desktop application

Comment: Actually, i didnt quite understand why it is a hack or it is forbidden. Only the user who knows the username and password can be authenticated and hence him fetching the cookies is a valid scenario, right?